# Hibernate Discord bot discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make a hibernate mode, where the bot doesen't do anything, but it stays online. I wrote some stuff below

```
    let configstuffs = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('config.json')) //figuring out if hibernate mode is on
    if (configstuffs.hibernate === true) {
    client.user.setPresence({ status: 'idle' })
    client.user.setActivity('Bot is hibernating')
    console.log('hibernating')
    return
    } else {
        client.user.setPresence({ status: 'online' })
        client.user.setActivity('')
        console.log('no longer hibernating')
    }
```

I put this outside of my message listener, inside my `bot.once('ready', () => {}` but it says something like 'cannot read property 'setPresence' of null.'

My goal is to make it so that when hibernate mode is active, the bot becomes idle, and sets its game as 'Hibernating' or something similar, then ignores all messages, or bypassing the message listener. Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a hibernate option in my bot and this is what I did

```js
let isHibernating = false; //Global (top level) variable
const Hibernate = (client) => {
    if(!client){ return(false) }
    client.user.setPresence({ //Sets detailed presence
        activity: {
            name: "Hibernating",
            type: "PLAYING"
        },
        status: "idle",
        afk: true
    });
    isHibernating = true;
}
```

And in your on-message handler

```js
client.on("message", message => {
    if(isHibernating){ return(false) } //Bot is Hibernating
    // other things
    if(message.content === "hibernate" && message.author.id == "Bot owner ID"){
        Hibernate(client);
    }
});
```